# Python/sqlite - selecting records after insert

Tags: python, sqlite

Is there an sqlite equivalent to INSERT...;SELECT @@IDENTITY?  If so, please show me the code or point me towards it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`Cursor.lastrowid`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.lastrowid)

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute("create table t (id integer, some text);")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00C64CE0>
>>> c.execute("insert into t values(1,'a');")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00C64CE0>
>>> c.lastrowid
1
```

Comment: Thanks!  This example worked perfectly for what I needed.  I didn't try the other answer, but assume it would have worked too.

Comment: Be careful using this method if you are making many changes within one cursor instance before calling commit(). You might not get the values you want.

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid() -- same as select @@identity
```

**last_insert_rowid()** The last_insert_rowid() function returns the ROWID of the last row insert from the database connection which invoked the function. The last_insert_rowid() SQL function is a wrapper around the sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() C/C++ interface function.